# Limit shown entries of nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an object like this:

```
data = {
  element1: ["content11", "content12"],
  element2: [],
  element3: ["content31"],
  element4: ["content41", "content42", "content43"]
}
```

Displaying everything with nested `ng-repeat` is straightforward:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in data">
  <div ng-repeat="content in element">
    {{content}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Which gives me the expected output:

> content11
>   content12
>   content31
>   content41
>   content42
>   content43

The number of elements is known, but the size of the arrays varies.
Now I'm struggling to limit the list of displayed elements to 4.

To spice things up, I want to show the first array entries first, then continue with the second, and so on. Which leads to the following code:

```
iteration = [0,1,2,3] //because I want to limit everything to 4 elements and don't care for more
```

```
<div ng-repeat="i in iteration">
  <div ng-repeat="content in data">
    {{content[i]}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Again the expected output, but still struggling with the limit:

> content11
>   content31
>   content41
>   content12
>   content42
>   content43

I tried to work with `$parent.$index` and `$index`, but was not successful to build a working counting function.

Unfortunately, I have to evaluate this data structure in each line of a large table and must keep an eye on performance.

Refactoring the object is for legacy reasons not possible.

Comment: To limit nested `ng-repeat` you need to flatten and pre-compute the list in advance (to know the length of it), since each row doesn't know any information (such as length) about the previous rows, therefore you cannot limit it to 4 elements so easily

Comment: Precomputing means to build a second object with limited number of entries or at least some break point index object.
I also have to keep the original object for filtering reasons, which should work on the whole dataset. 
I tried to avoid something like this and was looking for a more on the fly computing solution.

Comment: the simple and obvious example would look like this: [Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/CFXQ9f9lhi4nG8qLrv8q?p=preview)

Comment: @Blitzer lot of people tend to like these "on the fly" solutions until they understand that they are slow, hard to debug and hard to test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in iteration">
   <div ng-repeat="(type, content) in data" ng-show="content[i]  && countPreviousElements(data, i, $index) <= limit">
      {{content[i]}}
   </div>
</div>
```

and

```
  $scope.countPreviousElements = function(data, iteration, index){
    var sum = 0;
    var i = 0;
    for(var key in data){
      if(i<=index){
        sum += data[key].length > iteration+1 ? iteration+1 : data[key].length;
      }else{
        sum += data[key].length > iteration ? iteration : data[key].length;
      }
      i+=1;
    }
    return sum;
  };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/0mzTBZIDuk39BFjJ2wRi?p=preview

This seems to work as I expected and the 'limit' can be changed at runtime.

Let's discuss the performance. This function is called for each array element in `data`. After an analysis of the productive data, the sum of all elements within the arrays in `data` does not grow beyond 20 in every row, usually much smaller.

Inside the function we loop once over the length of `data`, which is fixed right now to 9 and not expected to grow.

If I have to do this several times in a table the costs still remain linear.

Hopefully there is no problem for this "on the fly" solution.